# -canOpenURL error when checking cydia:// scheme for jailbreak detection

Tags: ios, jailbreak, openurl, cydia

As part of the jailbreak detection I am checking if `cydia` app can be reached through opening its URL scheme. But I am getting the following error despite I've registered the scheme in `info.plist`. Any idea what's causing this error?

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cydia://package/com.example.package" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>cydia</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I have checked the [OSStatus error](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-10814) that you got and I can see that it means that the application is not in the launch services. I'm not sure but I think that it means that cydia is not present, maybe you can check with a cydia jailbreak device.

Comment: Ok. I would expect that when cydia is not present, the function will simply return false and not an error. I am running this on a Simulator only for now and I wonder if this can cause the error? I am waiting for a jailbroken device and will test it there for sure. Thanks.

Comment: Just tested this on a jailbroken device without any error. It works as expected. I guess it's the Simulator issue on the end.

Comment: Good to know. I'll upvote since I may need this info too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this on a jailbroken device without any error. It works as expected. I guess it's the Simulator issue on the end.